# Deleted action dispatch by mistake, how to get it back correctly so that i can load my local host server properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

```
C:\NEW\`charityapp`>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0
.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engi
ne.rb:527:in `routes': cannot load such file -- action_dispatch/routing/route_set
(LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/engine.rb:574:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in
tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (2
levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in
each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_stro
ngly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_eac
h'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
        from C:/NEW/charityapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/NEW/charityapp/config.ru:3:in `require'
        from C:/NEW/charityapp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/NEW/charityapp/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/NEW/charityapp/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/server.rb:199:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/r
ack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/l
ib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: try running `bundle install`

Comment: then also the same thing is coming

Comment: I think you should first `gem uninstall rails` then if you are using `rvm` then specify `rvm use 2.0.0` and then do `bundle install`, see if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
bundle exec gem pristine --all
```

Reverts all the gems in the bundle to their initial state (other than gems installed as :git dependencies)